# .Net installation issue with SqlServerPipelineHost and SqlServer.DtsMsg

Tags: sql-server-2005, installation, reference, pipeline

I added a web service consumer to a vb 2005 Windows app and tried to install it on another computer, which had an earlier version already installed (ClickOnce deployment). An error came up saying I needed to install Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost in the GAC. I added PipelineHost to the list of references and marked it Copy Local = true, rebuilt the solution, published it and tried to install it on that other computer.

This time it said I needed to install Microsoft.SqlServer.**DtsMsg**, however, that component does not show up on my list of .Net components.

Where do I go from here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to find the item in the Application Files list and to force Include them in the package.